# JPA - orm.xml validation fails on "id" tag

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jpa

I am having some trouble getting Eclipse to parse my orm.xml, it cannot seem to recognize the ID property of my entity. This class and orm.xml exist within a JSF application. Here is my simple class:

```
package mypackage;

public class Bar implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    
    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

And my orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">
    <schema>MYSCHEMA</schema>
    <entity class="mypackage.Bar" name="Bar">
        <table name="Bar"/>
        <attributes>
            <id name="foo">
            </id>
        </attributes>
    </entity> 
</entity-mappings>
```

With this setup, the following problem is produced in Eclipse: `Attribute "foo" in class "mypackage.Bar" cannot be resolved`

Things I have tried:

- Restarting Eclipse
- Re-adding the annotations that were present before the orm.xml file (my understanding was that these were unneeded when an orm.xml file is defined), those annotations were `@Entity` and `@Table(schema="MYSCHEMA", name="Bar")` for the `Bar` class and `@Id` for `foo`
- Defining a column within the id orm.xml tag

So, why is this property of my class not being recognized inside the orm.xml?

Comment: What's the package statement in the Bar class? It's not shown here.

Comment: ```package mypackage;```, question edited.